# Rest framework, working with curl and views

Tags: python, django

I am only beginning to use rest_framework and i am stuck already.
I have two projects in my local server. Both projects are identical in some way and one project must return some data through an api and the other project must receive those data and store them.

Keep in mind that, both projects will be running at different servers (different ports in current state). Now the problem is how do i get the dictionary values returned from an api of one app to another app in another project.

Like curl returns the dictionary in the shell:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <your-access-token>" http://localhost:8000/api/
```

is there some way to use curl in views of another project and get the dictionary values there or is there another picture for doing so? please, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use urllib from The Python Standard Library. Or consider using requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/